# How to enable the sidebar in finder?

Tags: finder

All out of a sudden, the sidebar in "Finder" is gone. The weird thing is that the "Show Sidebar" entry of the View menu is disabled/grayed out, so the sidebar can't be enabled again. Do you have any ideas how to fix this issue?
Btw, restarting did not change anything.

Edit: Happens on OSX Yosemite/10.10.3

Comment: do you get this on every window?  for instance start opening the hard drive on desktop and see if it's still greyed out.

Comment: Same behavior on every window. It seems like the sidebar is totally gone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully move the pointer to the left side of the finder window border till the cursor changes to arrow pointing to the right.

**↦**

Hold and Drag to the right.

If that did not work you need to restore the finders preferences.

In terminal run

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
```

and

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

Restart.

Answer (score 28):

For me, the solution is that I need first (by Apple mis-logic) to hit:

"View / Show Toolbar" (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>);

…then "View / Show Sidebar" (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) becomes ungreyed.

Comment: Still happening in 2020. Sad. But this workaround still works.

Comment: Works in Monterey

Comment: Works on Ventura ... doing ⌘⌥T (command + option + T) to show the toolbar was enough to force the sidebar to appear again. YMMV